# AEM column overlay classic UI - column list is changed

Tags: overlay, aem, apache-felix, aem-6

I was following the [tutorial](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-3/sites/developing/using/customizing-siteadmin.html) on how to customize AEM Console by adding a new column in classic UI. Everything works and I can see the new column displaying the data. Only one thing is bothering me:

Before the overlay, the OOTB column list is this one:

[image]

After the overlay:

[image]

Any idea how can I retain the OOTB list of columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OOTB list of columns are driven from `SiteAdmin.js` in `/libs/cq/ui/widgets/source/widgets/wcm`

Override this file under `apps` to add your custom column whilst retaining the other OOTB ones -

- Copy `SiteAdmin.js` from  `/libs/cq/ui/widgets/source/widgets/wcm` to `/apps/cq/ui/widgets/source/widgets/wcm`. The folders are of `jcr:primaryType` - `nt:folder`.

[image]

- Edit this file. Line 173 on my version(AEM 6.2 - shouldn't matter as this is to do with classic UI) lists the columns that are rendered. Add your custom column to the list. e.g.

  ```
              "columns": [
                  CQ.wcm.SiteAdmin.COLUMNS["numberer"],
                  CQ.wcm.SiteAdmin.COLUMNS["thumbnail"],
                  CQ.wcm.SiteAdmin.COLUMNS["title"],
                  CQ.wcm.SiteAdmin.COLUMNS["name"],
                  CQ.wcm.SiteAdmin.COLUMNS["published"],
                  CQ.wcm.SiteAdmin.COLUMNS["modified"],
                  CQ.wcm.SiteAdmin.COLUMNS["scene7Status"],
                  CQ.wcm.SiteAdmin.COLUMNS["status"],
                  CQ.wcm.SiteAdmin.COLUMNS["impressions"],
                  CQ.wcm.SiteAdmin.COLUMNS["template"],
                  CQ.wcm.SiteAdmin.COLUMNS["workflow"],
                  CQ.wcm.SiteAdmin.COLUMNS["locked"],
                  CQ.wcm.SiteAdmin.COLUMNS["liveCopyStatus"],
                  CQ.wcm.SiteAdmin.COLUMNS["starred"]
             ],
  ```
- You should now define the logic for this new column ('starred'). Line number 2006 onwards (search for `CQ.wcm.SiteAdmin.COLUMNS = {`) in the same file, you'll find the logic for each of the columns listed in the previous point. Add logic for the custom column.

  `"mime": {
          "header":CQ.I18n.getMessage("Kind"),
          "id":"mime",
          "hidden":true,
          "dataIndex":"mime"
      },
  "starred": {
      "header":CQ.I18n.getMessage("Starred"),
      "id":"starred",
      "dataIndex":"starred",
      "hidden":true,
      "renderer": function(val, meta, rec) {
          console.log("Rec " + rec)
          return rec.json.starred;
      }
  }`
- `rec.json.starred` value is computed in the `StarredListInfoProvider.java` file from the tutorial linked in your question.
- Save and you should see the OOTB columns along with your custom one.

[image]

- So from the tutorial, you just skip the `overlay` bit (`Displaying the New Column` section on the page) and use the `override` method mentioned above to retain all the OOTB columns.

---

**Additional Info**

- The third point i.e. logic for the custom column, I have added only `hidden: true` for now to make the column hidden by default and only be visible when you check it. There are several other public methods available in `CQ.Ext.grid.ColumnModel` that you can use to configure this further. Refer the [Widgets API](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-3/sites/developing/using/reference-materials/widgets-api/index.html?class=CQ.Ext.grid.ColumnModel) doc for more info.
- The tutorial describes computing the custom column value on the server side, you can achieve this on the javascript front as well. You'll have to register a javascript file in a `clientlib` and make sure the `categories` value of the clientlib matches the `categories` value of the library file. In the case of `SiteAdmin.js` it is `cq.widgets`, so your custom clientlib should also have the same `categories` value.
- When you override the file, at least on my machine I did not see the changes immediately, I had to delete the cached clientlibs under `/var/clientlibs` before I could see the changes. Use `console.log`, `debugger` or the usual chrome debugger to further understand logic behind this file.
- Using a tool like [FileVault](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-3/sites/developing/using/ht-vlttool.html) to get these changes onto your filesystem and add it to version control so that it propagates to rest of the environments through build pipeline, got to add an entry in `filter.xml` under `META-INF\vault` for the overridden folder to get picked up by maven.
- `Overriding` is *usually not recommended* as you might lose out on updates when Adobe releases a new version, but in this case `SiteAdmin.js` is specific to Classic UI and Adobe has stopped supporting Classic UI for good and in fact looking at removing Classic UI from 2019 release onwards. So I don't see any harm in overriding for this use case.

Comment: this is a very comprehensive and well documented answer. Thank you. Yeah, I was debugging this file and was thinking of such an approach, but wasn't sure if it would be a right way of doing it. Thank you again!

Comment: Glad I was able to help. The bounty was definitely a motivating factor ! :-) Just ensure the change is part of your build process - to make this production ready (the point about `filter.xml`, second last point in additional info section).